# The php tags in my html code make my html code run incorrectly

Tags: php, html, session

I am trying to make a simple website on which a visitor can make an account and login with that account. The register/login code has already been done and it works with a database.
When the user has logged in he/she will be redirected to the homepage but the homepage will be slightly changed.
Instead of two links in the navigation bar (Login and Register) there will be one link saying "My account".
I tried to do this by using this code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <?php
        if(!empty($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      ?>
        <li><a href='register.html'>My Account</a></li>
      <?php
        }else{
      ?>
                <li><a href='register.html'>Register</a></li>
                <li><a href='login.html'>Log in</a></li>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

The problem i have is that when the session is created, the two links disappear but the "My Account" link doesnt not appear.
What did i do wrong here?
Sorry for the bad title, it's 11:30 pm and english is not my native language.

For the people who want to see the login script:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

session_start();
$error = "";
$emailaddress = $_POST["emailaddress"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
if(empty($emailaddress) || empty($password)){
    $error = "Email or password is invalid!";
    echo $error;
}
else{
    $queryforlogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailaddress='$emailaddress' AND password='$password'");
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($queryforlogin);

    if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE emailaddress='$emailaddress'"));
        echo "Welcome, " . $_SESSION['login_user']['firstname'] . "!";
    }
    else{
        $error = "Email or password not found!";
        echo $error;
    }
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    mysql_close($connect);
}

?>
```

Comment: `mysql` is deprecated, use `mysqli`

Comment: @Nordenheim Thank you for the advice. I once learned php the old way and still have to switch to mysqli.

Comment: Your session variable is empty echo it and let us know what it states you don't have to echo your statement I have done it like yourself before and that works fine

Comment: @DJones Hi, It showed this: Resource id#8. Anything i can do with that?

Comment: It's not empty then... I have seen something though in your PHP you state if rows = to 1 however you select all from the db with the same email if there's 2 of the same row it won't output your code. Just in case change == to >= see if this makes a difference? Or limit 1 in your sql

Comment: @DJones It didn't do anything about the links but i am gonna keep the ">=" in my code. Seems more efficient. Thank you for that tip.

Comment: I've run the html and PHP through my server it was with manual manipulation so the first part of your code is fine the other part is the issue run var_dump($_SESSION['login_user']); and let's see what's happening with your sql

Comment: @DJones sorry for the delay. var dump returns: array(1) ["login_user"] -> NULL

Comment: It's empty then fix that and the other code should work